# Is that any way to set rtph264pay's profile-level-id in gst-good-1.8?

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, rtp

since i use gstreamer to transcode vp8 to h264 and sent to chrome,but profile-level-id don't match. so is that any way to set rtph264pay's profile-level-id in gst-good-1.8 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `h264parse` element after your `h264 encoder` would identify the profile-level-idc and put it into caps which you can then use.